# Verb meaning “giving people sh*t”

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, offensive-language

I'm looking for a specific verb that mean 'giving people shit' (as in teasing them, keeping them honest).

It needs to capture that the teasing is warranted, and that the criticism is correct.

Comment: Slang or formal register?

Comment: @LittleEva formal please :)

Comment: Really? I didn't think that "shit" was a bad enough word to warrant bleeping...

Comment: @Catija The line has to come somewhere; wherever it does people will disagree that words "just over it" are/not "bad enough".

Comment: I reverted the edit back to the uncensored version - thought I guess 'sh*t' is ok. 
relevant metas:
http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/253/referencing-the-existence-of-words-that-may-be-offensive

http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/253/referencing-the-existence-of-words-that-may-be-offensive

It looks like there isn't a hard and fast policy about whether swearing should be allowed in the titles

Comment: specific meta here
http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6958/should-swearing-be-allowed-in-titles?lq=1

Comment: To *give shit to somebody*, is not an expression I'm familiar with. The ones *I* know are: "Don't give me that shit" or "Don't give me any of your shit" or "I don't give a shit". All used in the negative. But none of which mean teasing, or poking fun at someone.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference which has that definition.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's mostly American, but _give sb. shit_ is an idiom that means to nag at them or bicker at them, sometimes (though not necessarily) in a teasing way. It's more or less akin to _giving sb. a hard time_, and it's frequently followed by _about_ (“She's always giving him shit about his bad grades”, for instance). Curiously, it doesn't really seem to be in any easily findable reference works—or maybe it's just hard to find because it's hard to Google for.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet is nagging the same as "teasing" or "keeping them honest"?  To *tease* someone is to make fun of them, to jeer, or even taunt, in a light-hearted manner, or cruelly; but I don't see how that is related to "She's always giving him shit about his school grades".

Comment: In some senses, it could be describing philanthropy. ^_^

Comment: @Mari-LouA Giving people shit is generally more negative than teasing, I would say, but it can be used more humorously too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider ***razz***. It is an informal verb but captures both teasing and criticism.

> - to make playful or unkind comments about (someone) *[[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/razz)*
> - to deride, jeer; to mock or make fun of (a person or thing). *[OED]*

Comment: There are a couple more synonyms for [harass with persistent criticism or carping](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/razz) listed here, though they're all homonyms of something else. (*rag*, *ride*, etc).  So +1 to *razz*.

Comment: As a followup question, is this why the raspbery awards are shortened to "razzie awards"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Raspberry_Awards

Comment: @private_meta: Razz is also a short name for raspberry

Comment: And example would be useful

Answer (score 5):

To poke fun at someone, but benevolently, is to "*josh*"

> [**josh**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/josh)
>
> *intransitive verb*: to engage in banter: joke
>
> *transitive verb*: to tease good-naturedly: kid
>
> **Examples** of JOSH
>
> • “Don't take him seriously. He's just *joshing*”
>
> • “Don’t get all hot and bothered! I'm just *joshing* you”
>
> **Synonyms**: chaff, jive, joke, tease, kid, rally, razz, rib, ride, roast

(Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 4):

Consider the word **needle**.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aneedle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) defines it as:

> provoke or annoy (someone), especially by continual criticism or questioning.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/needle) defines it as:

> to criticize and laugh at (someone) in either a friendly or an unkind way
>
> tease, torment

Comment: Needle is charactised by _continual_ critcism.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the plethora of UK colloquial slang, the only single verb I can think of that I still see regularly in books or hear in conversation is;

[**Mock**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mock)

> to criticize and laugh at (someone or something) for being bad, worthless, or unimportant
>
> to laugh at or make fun of (someone or something) especially by copying an action or a way of behaving or speaking

*"They continue to mock the idea of a new government"*

For something a little more light hearted;

[**Jest**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jest)

> something said or done to cause laughter
>
> an utterance (as a jeer or quip) intended to be taken as mockery or humour

*"you should know that our teasing was done entirely in jest"*

Answer (score 3):

Wind-up is a word I may use, however it may not fit your one word request, so I propose:

> **Antagonise**
>
> to make hostile; annoy or irritate

Definition from Collins Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

The term *[twit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/twit)* might be useful

> Tease or taunt (someone), especially in a good-humored way.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

It is usually used when the object of the poke is in the wrong

> To taunt, ridicule, or tease, especially for embarrassing mistakes or faults

*[American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=twit)*

Similarly, *[tweak](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tweak)*

> To make fun of; tease.

*American Heritage*

**Supplement:** Also consider *[chide](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/chide)*

> Scold or rebuke: *she chided him for not replying to her letters*
>
> [WITH DIRECT SPEECH]: *“You mustn’t speak like that,” she chided gently*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: I'm guessing "twit" is British slang?  I've never heard it used this way in America --although "twit" is occasionally used as a term for a pompous dimwit.

Comment: Yeah, *tweak* works in the US, *twit* not so much.

Comment: 'Twit' is very British, although I feel its use was much more prevalent in the 'Monty Python' era.

Comment: @myol Wait! This is NOT the Monty Python era?!

Answer (score 2):

The word is **chastise**:

> to criticize (someone) harshly for doing something wrong
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chastise

or

> 1. to inflict suffering upon for purposes of moral improvement;
>      to discipline, especially by corporal punishment.
> 2. to criticize severely.
> 3. Archaic. to restrain; chasten.
> 4. Archaic. to refine; purify.
>      http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chastise?s=t

You could intensify it to **chasten**:

> to correct by punishment or suffering :  discipline; also :  purify
>   to cause to be more humble or restrained :
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chasten

or

> to inflict suffering upon for purposes of moral improvement;
>   http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chasten

If the connotation of moral improvement, wasn't essential, I would go with *harass* or *harangue*.

Comment: Doesn't imply teasing at all.

Answer (score 1):

The (probably [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English)) word I always heard for this growing up was `ragging`. It was kind of a sport at my school. You never knew when an impromptu game of [Dozens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dozens) might break out, so it paid to keep your skills sharp and figure out everyone's weaknesses up front.

Ragging doesn't *have* to be true. However, it will be far more effective the more truth it contains. For instance, someone with a skinny mother is probably not going to be impacted very much by a "Yo' momma so fat..." snap.